# Angular 2 | RXjs issue with distinctUntilChanged after updating view

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an issue with RXjs' distinceUntilChanged on input field after changing the value on JavaScript.

Steps to reproduce:

1. set text "a" inside the input
2. click on the remove button >> as result the input is empty, with using of javascript
3. set again "a" inside the input
4. click again on the remove button. but now the input stays with the "a" value

If we would insert another value that is different from 'a', it will work.
Of course, if I remove distinceUntilChanged from my observable, it will work as well.

Code snippet:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app',
template: `
        <input #input [value]="value ? value : ''" (input)="filter$.next(input.value)">

        {{val}}
        <div>
            <button (click)=remove()>Remove</button>
        </div>
   `
   })

export class App {

  filter$ = new Subject();
  val:string;
  value:string;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filter$
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe((value) => {
        this.val = value;
        this.value = value;
    }));
    }

    remove(){
    console.log('test');
    this.value = "";
    this.val = "";
   }

 }
```

I created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JRaSpc2QukKK22H9DeWd?p=preview) example with my problem:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're just changing the display's text. Your remove function should look like this:

```
remove() {
  this.filter$.next("")
}
```